# How ordering between sub reports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have one report has two sub reports(A and B)
How to get B initializing after A,because B has a parameter is depended to A
Another hand how ordering between sub reports in jasper
Is it possible?my request is logical?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can manage your order with a management on your report structure.

If possible:

You have a `MAIN` report

Under the `MAIN` report you can define a sub-report named `A`.

In the sub-report A you can define a sub-report B (so all B linked to your `A` will be exposed after the main A).

A simple example:

Main report: List of Italian football team of Lega Pro level (for example Taranto, Matera, Foggia and so on). This is your MAIN report.

For each team you have a list of football players.

To explode this list for each team, you have to define a sub-report named A.

For each player you want to show all matches where this player have taken apart.

You have to define a sub-report named B under A.

**UPDATE**

To manage this flow:

Main Information
A information (all rows)
B information (all rows)

**The first part:**
Definition of your data structure

You must have a main object with two listes.

A list for A information
A list for B information

**The second part:**

Definition of report structure

You must define two different subreport as follow:

In the main report you add two details band.

In the first detail band add a link to subreport A

In the second detail band add a link to subreport B

In this way. As first you process all A rows and the you'll process all B rows

Comment: if B is defined into A that each row of B is depended to each row of A but B and A is indepeneded together.this solution is not for my problem

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin: Please write better your request, because I suppose (B has a parameter depending by A) your A and B are depending entities

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin: Please write too, with an example, how do you want show the flow of this report

Comment: B is depended to result of A not to each row of A

Comment: So you want to show all A rows and then all B rows. Right?

Comment: Yes Is it possible?

Comment: thanks so much for answering.Is your answer is updated

Comment: is it possible with one details band.

Comment: Is it possible with one details band because i want to beside together.another hand A is one column and B is another column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134292/discussion-between-reza-ramezani-matin-and-joe-taras).

Comment: I don't downvote your question. I don't know because it happened but if another read our comments, I write to add in your question some other important information to be clear your question. On your question there's a procedure about close it. Enlarge your question before it's too late.

Comment: Is it possible with one details band

Comment: Depends how you want to show your report. If you can't use ireport to crete a preview open Paint and add a screenshot of your hypotetical report

Comment: Not important style of view,Any thing of view is solve my report is good,Any thing of view is designed by you is ok

Comment: For example you suppose two column that one of them is A and another  is B and A has two column and B has three column